# Show two different applications on dual monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have an external monitor attached to my laptop, and I'm running Windows 8 on my laptop. My question is can I show different desktops on each monitor, for example to open an application on my laptop's monitor and another application on the external monitor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [YES](http://www.itproportal.com/2012/07/17/how-to-utilise-multiple-displays-in-windows-8/) and [YES](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406969,00.asp). In your

```
ControlPanel>Appearance and Personalization>Display
```

you will have Extend/Duplicate settings. Choose Extend. Now you can use your second application on the second display!

Comment: but how can I access the desktop on the external monitor ?

Comment: Because the desktop has been extended, the two monitors are now 'connected'. For example, if monitor A is to the left of monitor B, when you scroll your mouse from A to the right, the mouse pointer will continue to scroll to monitor B.

Answer (score 0):

First it depends on your laptop graphics capability.

I'm not Windows 8 user, but as [per MS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/multiple-monitors#1TC=t1) you can

> Open desktops apps on all monitors, or open apps from the Windows
>   Store on one and desktop apps on the others.

I used two different laptops with Intel and ATI graphics, first with Win7 and second one with Ubuntu 10.04-12.04 and both worked fine in dual monitor mode.

Answer (score -1):

This method doesn't work for me, as I have no "Display" option , but sounds like it could be helpful for others.   ControlPanel>Appearance and Personalization>Display

Comment: This information was already give 7 years ago, along with more helpful information that actually answered the question. Unless you have something significant and helpful to add, do not post answers that merely repeat answers already given.